# Excel file name issue in send mail task using SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have a package which is creating a excel file 'ExcelName.xls' and storing in 'E:\Reporting\Delivered_Reports'. Now I have to attach this report using send mail task and send it to given mail id. To achieve this I have configured the send mail task and in Expression Builder, I have selected the below expression:

```
"E:\\Reporting\\Delivered_Reports\\ExcelName_"+
((DT_WSTR,4)Year(@[System::StartTime]))+
RIGHT("0"+((DT_WSTR,2)Month(@[System::StartTime])),2)+
RIGHT("0"+((DT_WSTR,2)Day(@[System::StartTime])),2)+".xls"
```

I need file name should be 'ExcelName_20150601' where suffix is the current date. But I recieve file which name is 'ExcelName', which is the origional file name. Can you tell me where I am wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are editing the name of the excel file in the email, instead of using a file system task to actually rename the file prior to sending it.  You can't rename the file using the send mail task, as far as I know.

Additionally, I would do the date to string conversion in a separate variable in order to make this easier to debug, or even put both values in variables to ease maintenance.

Create a variable "var_today" or something and put this code in it:

```
((DT_WSTR,4)Year(@[System::StartTime]))+
RIGHT("0"+((DT_WSTR,2)Month(@[System::StartTime])),2)+
RIGHT("0"+((DT_WSTR,2)Day(@[System::StartTime])),2)
```

Then your expression becomes:

```
"E:\\Reporting\\Delivered_Reports\\ExcelName_"+
@[User::var_date]+".xls"
```

Do the same for the root directory.

Comment: Hi Eric, can you please tell me the steps as I am very new to SSIS? Thanks in advance

Comment: I have written a script So it generated filename 'Daily_Report_20150602' with date at last. Its saving into 'E:\ReportFolder'. Now how to attach this file and send through send mail task, as tomorrow this file name will be 'Daily_Report_20150603'. So how to achieve this?

Comment: If the filename is stored in a variable, then it will automatically change its value each day.

Answer (score 0):

it is better to make the filename you wanted while you are generating from the package.
you cant change the name while sending and put your filename in a string variable instead of writing it directly.
@[User::File_Name]+@[User::date]+".xlsx"
something like this

Comment: Hi rahul,
                  can you please tell me the steps as I am very new to SSIS?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have written a script So it generated filename 'Daily_Report_20150602' with date at last. Its saving into 'E:\ReportFolder'. Now how to attach this file and send through send mail task, as tomorrow this file name will be 'Daily_Report_20150603'. So how to achieve this?

Comment: "E:\\Reporting\\Delivered_Reports\\ExcelName_"+
@[User::var_date]+".xls"
use this expressions only date as variable you should use it will work

Comment: Hi rahul,
              But date i am calculating in script itself, So everytime it generates the report with date like 'Daily_Report_20150602''. This output I am getting from script task. Now I have to mail this, So how to configure send mail task and expression. Sorry I am asking too many questions but I dont know how to achieve this.

Comment: storing the filename as variable will pick the file with the cuurent date  . make sure your have set delay validation to true. it is working for me